# Laravel performance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I was going to port a custom webstore application to Laravel, so that it's new, shiny and is a pleasure to support. After spending a couple of hours on setting up the framework and starting to port the main layout, I decided to test how it performs. I have installed a copy of my original app and the ported part to laravel, where I set up a Section model with a translation from dimsav/laravel-translatable and output the main navigation with Section::all() of about 30 sections.

I was shocked when I saw the result of simple observation of the Netwrok tab in Firebug:

For my laravel setup it takes roughly **360ms** to render just the above. I imagine how much the response time will be when the whole page would be ported...

For the original app it takes ~**30ms** to serve the whole homepage with the same navigation, popular products, submenus, footer navigation, checking cart contents etc.

Both on the same virtual server and even using the same database, no caching in either.

I profiled the code to discover any issues, but all I found is that

- 6.4% is spent on autoloading (32ms - more than the whole requesto for the other version),
- 12.5%/63ms - service registerting
- 11.1%/56ms - configuration loadig
- 44.5% on endless Pipline calls. about the time seems to be spent on endless Pipeline calls.

Just to confirm, an empty laravel app responds in about 17ms.

Am I missing somethign here? I imagined there would be some performance degrade when moving to the framework, but (assuming the reponse time will increase for the complete setup, so I would expect ~20x) 20x seems crazy. Are these time normal for laravel and is there any big win from using caching (Redis for instance) or any other optimization techinques? I wonder if there actually are any except for caching?

Comment: Do you have many routes? Thats been known to be a bottleneck in past versions, which led to the introduction of [route caching](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#route-caching).

Comment: No, i just started the migration, so it's actually 2 routes - one for the hompage and the default one that ships with laravel I chnaged the URI for. 
Laravel is fresh install, so it's 5.1.

Comment: What are you doing in your controller,or bulk of your program? How long do your queries take to execute? Whats your server spec? Are you caching anything on your current webstore (queries, etc).

Comment: Contoroller just returns a view. In the view, a navigation helper is injected which returns Section::categories()->public()->get();, categories and public being scopes with primitive conditions. The Translations are being loaded as a one-to-many relationship. That;s it.
As I have mentioned in the question, no caching is set up for either of the applications.

Comment: How's the subsequent requests? Is it on 300ms or so? Laravel are known to load slower on initial request - compiling and things. But it'll gradually decreased as no more changes to compile.

Comment: Well, my research has lead me to the conclusion this has something to with virtualbox shared folders It was much faster when run an a real VPS.

Comment: @Okneloper Common issue with Virtualbox, you'll want to turn on NFS for shared folders.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, NFS is not an option though, since the host is windows.

Answer (score 1):

On a $5 VPS instance from Digital Ocean with deployed apps I see response times:

512MBMemory
1 Core Processor
20GBSSD Disk

Lumen 60-120 ms
Laravel 100-300 ms

These particular apps do not caching. The 100-150 ms response time seems to be the base response time with laravel for a view that has already been compiled. Obviously having slow queries will increase that.

Adding redis or memcached will dramatically degrease your response time compared to going to the db in most cases getting pretty close to the base response time of laravel.

You should make sure to set APP_DEBUG to false in your .env file:

```
# /.env
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Run `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Thanks. Not sure Lumen would be appropriate for an ecom. 
As i have said in the comments above this was not an issue on a real VPS (ie not a local VM). Sorry, I don't have the numbers accessible.

Comment: Well just added Lumen for added detail you would be correct that it doesn't apply to your use case. Glad you got it figured out :)